# Numerically stable way to compute (x-sin(x))/x^3

Tags: precision, trigonometry

I'm looking for a very fast way to compute (x-sin(x))/(x^3) for all x using IEEE floating point arithmetic and standard trigonometric functions. At 0, it should return 1/6.

For sin(x)/x, it's sufficient to check if x=0 and return 1, otherwise just compute it using standard floating point sin and division. For (1-cos(x))/x^2, if cos(x) <= 0, this expression is fine as is and otherwise express as (sin(x)/x)^2/(1+cos(x))

But I can't figure out how to express (x-sin(x))/x^3.

So far, the best I have is to compute the infinite sum until it converges: $\sum_0^{\infty}{1/4^(n+1)*sin(x/2^n)/(x/2^n)*(1-cos(x/2^n))/(x/2^n)^2}$
but I'd prefer a closed form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(1 - cos x) / x<sup>2</sup>* is fundamentally different from *(x - sin x) / x<sup>3</sup>*, in that unity can be constructed by trigonometric functions as *sin<sup>2</sup> x + cos<sup>2</sup> x = 1*, while the same is not true of *x*. This means we cannot transform the latter function into a *numerically advantageous* closed-form trigonometric formula. I thought long about this and also tried manipulating the formula with all trigonometric identities I am aware of. I would love to be proven wrong; that seems like a question for Math Stack Exchange. The easiest and most accurate way to implement the former function is

```c
// (1-cos(x))/x**2
double cosm1_over_xsquared (double x)
{
    if (fabs (x) < sqrt (DBL_EPSILON)) {
        return 0.5;
    } else {
        double s = sin (x * 0.5) / x;
        return 2.0 * s * s;
    }
}
```

If the standard math library computes `sin()` with an error just slightly over half an ulp, this implementation computes *(1 - cos x) / x<sup>2</sup>* with an error no larger than 4 ulp. As a side-note, this function also lends itself to the use of Kahan's self-correction technique, which he first demonstrated for the computation of *(e<sup>x</sup> - 1) / x* in

William M. Kahan, "Interval arithmetic in the proposed IEEE floating point arithmetic standard." In Karl L. E. Nickel (ed.), *Interval Arithmetic 1980*, Academic Press 1980, pp. 99-128.

```c
// (1-cos(x))/x**2 on [-3, 3] using Kahan's self-compensation technique
double cosm1_over_xsquared_kahan (double x)
{
    double u = cos (x);
    double n = 1.0 - u;
    if (n == 0.0) {
        return 0.5;
    }
    double d = acos (u);
    return n / (d * d);
}
```

If both `cos()` and `acos()` have a maximum error just slightly over half an ulp, this function returns results with an error of less than 5 ulps. Because *cos*, other than *e<sup>x</sup>* is a periodic function, this approach works only on the restricted interval noted in the code comment.

The above suggests that we should shoot for an implementation of *(x - sin x) / x<sup>3</sup>* with a maximum error of about 4 ulp. Characterizing the naive computation, we find that it is adequate for *|x| > 1* under this provision. Despite the narrow input domain for an alternate computation, Kahan's self-compensation technique does *not* work for this function. The old standby of math function implementers, a polynomial minimax approximation, works just fine, however. This results in the following code:

```c
// (x-sin(x))/x**3
double sinmx_over_xcubed (double x)
{
    if (fabs(x) < 1.0) { // minimax approximation
        double x2 = x * x;
        double p =   7.5475867852548673E-13;
        p = p * x2 - 1.6057658525730946E-10;
        p = p * x2 + 2.5052098906959416E-8;
        p = p * x2 - 2.7557319191306421E-6;
        p = p * x2 + 1.9841269841218293E-4;
        p = p * x2 - 8.3333333333333055E-3;
        p = p * x2 + 1.6666666666666666E-1;
        return p;
    } else {
        return (x - sin (x)) / x / x / x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well the Taylor series for this expression is:

```
1/6 - x^2/120 + x^4/5040 + O(x^6)  (converges when x!=0)
```

Which should be pretty good for most applications.

## Addendum

If you are trying to find the limit at 0 for this: then, apply the L'Hôpital's rule since this is of form 0/0 for lim x->0

lim(x->0) (x-sin(x))/x^3 = lim(x->0) (1 - cos(x))/3x^2 = lim(x->0) = sin(x)/6x = lim(x->0) = 1/6 ;

In other words, it's probably best to use an if statement and for the case of (x = 0) and then use Taylor series which will be a LOT faster than doing floating point sin and cos unless you have purpose-built hardware or are using GPUs.

Comment: Of course I could always set a cutoff at which I just use the exact expression, but at this point we're still looking at algorithms that are either too slow or too imprecise depending on how many terms we include. This is not at all the same as having a closed-form expression and I would only use it if there _isn't_ a closed-form expression I could use instead which this answer doesn't demonstrate